# Kotlin MediaType.parse("something") is an error. moved to extension fucntion

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

Trying to create JSON type header for OkHttp3

`val JSONtype = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")`

But the following error is coming :

*Using 'parse(String):MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function*

Shown solution/suggestion:

`val JSONType = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull()`

Do the serve the same action or requirement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

You can check out migration guide:

https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/#extension-functions

Answer (score 14):

Instead of

```
 MediaType.parse(yourString)
```

use

```
 yourString?.toMediaTypeOrNull()
```

Comment: Yep! This is the import: `import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull`

Answer (score 5):

[image: source]

Here is a link to doc [Upgrading to OkHttp 4](https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/#extension-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Solution.
Convert String to RequestBody

```
 val description = binding.txtDescription.text.toString()
     
 val description_reqbody = description.toRequestBody("text/plain;charset=utf-8".toMediaType())
```

Cheers!